# Is it as dangerous to modify DKIM domain's public key, as to get a domains' sending private keys?

Tags: email, email-server, spam, dkim, domainkeys

I've been reading about DKIM and one of the reasons it cannot be "hacked" is because an attacker doesn't have access to a server's DKIM private key.

But what if the attacker has access to the domain's DNS records? What stops them from generating their own separate public/private key pair, and then starts sending?

Is the threat level of doing this the same as obtaining the private DKIM keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an attacker has full control of your DNS records you've got **bigger problems** than spam email being sent. Yes, they'd be able to send email that looks legitimately from your domain if they can change DKIM/SPF records.

The correct solution is *not to let them get control of your DNS*.